# Delete multiple contacts from a list input

Tags: contacts, delete, multiple-choice

Civi is a great platform and I started to use with the first action to organize some old contacts. I could import them fine and I see them in the system.
The problem is that we are doing some cross-checking for the accounts' current validity and at some point we need to delete some of them but based on a list of items, let's say emails that should be inputted somehow.
So the question is: is there an option like that? An input area like the "import contacts" where we can upload a file (maybe csv or text) with the emails to delete, then the script would just remove the contacts found.

Thank you very much!

Andy

Answer (score 2):

You could easily import a list of emails, add the contacts to a group when you import, and the delete all the members of the group.

The only potential hurdle is if you have more than one contact with the same email address, in which case the contacts will be imported as new contacts. In that case, I would suggest finding duplicate contacts of any members of your newly created group with a email matching rule and you can merge as appropriate to delete those contacts or simply deal with the matching contacts manually. If you want to delete all contacts with email addresses on your list, you could simply merge all the duplicate contacts found and then delete.